# Replace all tags within a <div> tag with <br> tag if no data is inside <div> tags and <br> is there using Regular expression in php

Tags: php, html

Actually, I want to eliminate all tags under `<div>` tag including `<div>` also only if there is `<br>` tag inside it.

For Example:

```
     <div>
          <font face="Arial, Verdana">
             <span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">
               <u>
                fs
               </u>
           </span>
        </font>
     </div>
     <div>
        <br>
     </div>
     <div>
          <font face="Arial, Verdana">
            <span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">
               <u>
                   <br>
                </u>
            </span>
          </font>
     </div>
     <div>
            <font face="Arial, Verdana">
            <span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">
                 <u>
                    <br>
                  </u>
            </span>
            </font>
     </div>
     <div>
          <font face="Arial, Verdana">
              <span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">
                <u>
                   <br>
                 </u>
               </span>
          </font>
     </div>
```

Its output should come:

```
     <div>
        <font face="Arial, Verdana">
           <span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">
             <u>
                fs
             </u>
           </span>
        </font>
     </div>
     <br>
     <br>
     <br>
```

Please someone tell me how to do this..

Comment: dont use regex for this, use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: You might want to consider [one of the many DOM parser libraries of PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php). In general using regex alone to parse HTML is not a good idea.

Comment: you need to sort out all the other horrible tags too though....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) with [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for better results:

```
/* Init DOMDocument: */
$dom = new DOMDocument();
/* Load HTML: */
libxml_use_internal_errors( True );
$dom->loadHTML( $html, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$dom->formatOutput = True;
/* Init DOMXPath: */
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

/* Search for all <body> <div> children (assuming your <div> are <body> children): */
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//body/div' );

foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    /* Search for <div> <br> children and - if found it - replace <div> by <br>: */
    $br = $node->getElementsByTagName( 'br' );
    if( $br->length )
    {
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild( $br->item(0), $node );
    }
}

/* Echo modified HTML: */
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result:

```
<div>
    <font face="Arial, Verdana">
        <span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">
            <u>
                fs
            </u>
        </span>
    </font>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Assuming your HTML Markup is stored in a Variable called $div; 
Here's what I'd do:

 if(preg_match("#(<br\/>|<br>|<br)*#", $div)){
  $div = strip_tags($div);
 }
 //USE THE FILTERED $div VARIABLE...
        echo $div;

Comment: Thank You . But, I also don't want to replace anything in the following case:  <div>
           <font face="Arial, Verdana">
            <span style="font-size: 13.3333px;"><br>
               <u>
               Hello World!
            </u><br>
        </span>
    </font>
</div>        Means when there is <br> tag and some text also.. Then no changes are required.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.1.6 but it does not support DOMDocument.. plz tell me some package to make it work without upgrading PHP to any other version for Fedora.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) you can find an (almost) complete list of available HTML/XML parsers. DOM is available also on PHP 5.1. You have only to install it through yum. Also seriously consider updating PHP: your version is obsolete and not supported.